# PyOpenCL kron Kernel

Tags: python, c, kernel, pyopencl

Main code:

```
from definitions import *
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy
from time import time

N = 16
num_iter = 10

a = numpy.random.rand(N,N).astype(numpy.float32)
b = numpy.random.rand(N,N).astype(numpy.float32)

print('Starting native iterations...')
startTime = time()
for i in range(num_iter):
    c = numpy.kron(a, b)

endTime = time()
print(endTime - startTime)
print()

context = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(context)

h_C = numpy.empty(c.shape).astype(numpy.float32)

d_a = cl.Buffer(context, cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY | cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=abig)
d_b = cl.Buffer(context, cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY | cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=bbig)
d_c = cl.Buffer(context, cl.mem_flags.WRITE_ONLY, h_C.nbytes)

print('Starting GPU tiling iterations...')

kernelsource = open("../tiling.cl").read()
program = cl.Program(context, kernelsource).build()
kronecker = program.kronecker
kronecker.set_scalar_arg_dtypes([numpy.int32, None, None, None, None, None])
d_a = cl.Buffer(context, cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY | cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=a)
d_b = cl.Buffer(context, cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY | cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=b)
h_C = numpy.empty(c.shape).astype(numpy.float32)

startTime = time()
for n in range(num_iter):
    # Work-group computes a block of C. This size is also set
    # in a #define inside the kernel function. Note this blocksize
    # must evenly divide the matrix order
    blocksize = 16

    A_block = cl.LocalMemory(numpy.dtype(numpy.float32).itemsize*blocksize*blocksize)
    B_block = cl.LocalMemory(numpy.dtype(numpy.float32).itemsize*blocksize*blocksize)
    kronecker(queue, (N*N,N*N), (blocksize,blocksize), N, d_a, d_b, d_c, A_block, B_block)
    queue.finish()

endTime = time()
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, h_C, d_c)

print(numpy.allclose(c,h_C))    
print(endTime-startTime)
print()
```

Kernel Code:

```
__kernel void kronecker(
                const unsigned int             N,
                __global const float* restrict A,
                __global const float* restrict B,
                __global       float* restrict C,
                __local        float* restrict Awrk,
                __local        float* restrict Bwrk)
{
    //  This work-item will compute element C(i,j)
    const int i = get_global_id(0);
    const int j = get_global_id(1);

    // Element C(i,j) is in block C(Iblk,Jblk)
    const int Iblk = get_group_id(0);
    const int Jblk = get_group_id(1);

    // C(i,j) is element C(iloc, jloc) of block C(Iblk, Jblk)
    const int iloc = get_local_id(0);
    const int jloc = get_local_id(1);

    // Construct an element of A and B to be shared between threads one element per thread.

    Awrk[Iblk+Jblk*N] = A[Iblk+Jblk*N];
    Bwrk[iloc+jloc*N] = B[iloc+jloc*N];
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    C[i+j*N*N] = Awrk[Iblk+Jblk*N] * Bwrk[iloc+jloc*N];

}
```

This code 100% works when N = 16 (or whenever I can choose `blocksize = N`). But due to limitations by the hardware, 16 is the maximum size for workgroup dimensions. I need a way to generalize this code in order to work with potentially any N that obviously doesn't ask for too much memory. The issue is that if the `blocksize` doesn't match `N`, the logic of choosing elements of A and B isn't sound anymore. Specifically, the block and local id's moves on too soon (the element of `A` and `B` changes after a blocksize-by-blocksize chunk of `C` instead of after a N-by-N chunk). Would the best way of fixing this be by adding modulus logic within the kernel when handling the id's or by nesting kernel calls so that each workgroup gets further divided to match the blocksize?